# How can I assign more than one "CssClass" to a control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

Can I assign more than one "CssClass" to a control in asp.net?How to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To assign class "myClass1" and "myClass2" you simply say:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="myClass1 myClass2" />
```

This is the same approach you'd use in normal HTML as in:

```
<div class="myClass1 myClass2"></div>
```

Comment: The order that they appear also matters, so if you set the font-size to 12px in myClass1 but myClass2 sets the font-size to 10px, then myClass2 will take precedence even though it appears last.

Answer (score 12):

If you wanted to add another class programmatically and don't know what classes have already been added

```
MyControl.CssClass += " newclass";
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for this answer for 2 hours!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the eqivalent of:

class="class1 class2"

So if it's a property just try throwing the classes with a space between them in there.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's just like setting the class attribute in an XHTML element.

```
<p class="foo bar"></p>

<asp:Something CssClass="foo bar" runat="server" />
```